# Resolve WebApi action Url from within MVC View using MVC.UrlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've created a helper extension which allows me to have strongly typed expressions with `UrlHelper` in MVC razor. This works very well for resolving URIs for my MVC Controllers from with in views.

```
<a href="@(Url.Action<HomeController>(c=>c.Index()))">Home</a>
<li>@(Html.ActionLink<AccountController>("Sign in", c => c.Signin(null)))</li>
<li>@(Html.ActionLink<AccountController>("Create an account", c => c.Signup(), htmlAttributes: null))</li>
@using (Html.BeginForm<ToolsController>(c => c.Track(null), FormMethod.Get, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "navbar-form", role = "search" })) {...}
```

I now have a view where I am trying to use knockout to post some data to my web api and need to be able to do something like this

```
var targetUrl = '@(Url.HttpRouteUrl<TestsApiController>(c => c.TestAction(null)))';
```

so that I don't have to hard code my urls (Magic strings)

My current implementation of my extension method for getting the web API url is defined as follows.

```
private const string HttpRouteKey = "httproute";
public static string HttpRouteUrl<TController>(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Expression<Action<TController>> action)
   where TController : System.Web.Http.ApiController {
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues = InternalExpressionHelper.GetRouteValues(action);
    if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(HttpRouteKey)) {
        routeValues.Add(HttpRouteKey, true);
    }
    var scheme = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
    var route = urlHelper.Action(null, null, rvd, scheme);
    //I've also tried
    //var route = urlHelper.HttpRouteUrl(null, rvd);
    return route;
}
```

`InternalExpressionHelper.GetRouteValues` inspects the expression and generates a `RouteValueDictionary` that will be used to generate the url.

Problem is that my `route` always returns `null`. Previous questions on SO and blogs found have indicated that by including the `httproute` in the dictionary would allow for the ability to get WebApi Urls from `MVC.UrlHelper` route collection.

So far none of the accepted answers seem to be working for me as I am using attribute routing without route name.

Comment: FYI, there is already an open source library to do that [here](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr).

Comment: I'm already digging through the source to see how it's being done there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as when generating links to Web API routes one must always require a `RouteName` for this to work, I decided to apply a convention.

The helper extension with determine the RouteName by combining the controller name and action name.

```
var routeName = string.Join("_", controllerName, actionName);
```

Now because when extraction information from the expression of which controller name and action name are included, they were also being shown in the url. not very pretty.

```
/api/tests/1/2?controller=TestsApi&amp;action=Get
```

so they were removed from the route values.

```
routeValues.Remove("controller");
routeValues.Remove("action");
```

The update extension method now looks like this

```
private const string HttpRouteKey = "httproute";
public static string HttpRouteUrl<TController>(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Expression<Action<TController>> action)
   where TController : System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController {
    var routeValues = InternalExpressionHelper.GetRouteValues(action);
    if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(HttpRouteKey)) {
        routeValues.Add(HttpRouteKey, true);
    }

    var controllerName = routeValues["controller"] as string;
    routeValues.Remove("controller");
    var actionName = routeValues["action"] as string;
    routeValues.Remove("action");

    var routeName = string.Join("_", controllerName, actionName);

    var url = urlHelper.HttpRouteUrl(routeName, routeValues);

    return url;
}
```

And now I just need to make sure that if I want my action to be accessible for url/link generation from MVC or Web API, a `RouteName` must be applied that follows the convention `"{controller}_{action}"`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tests")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestsApiController : WebApiControllerBase {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{lat:double:range(-90,90)}/{lng:double:range(-180,180)}", Name = "TestsApi_Get")]
    public object Get(double lat, double lng) {
        return new { lat = lat, lng = lng };
    }
}
```

Works for the most part so far when I test it

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = '@(Url.HttpRouteUrl<TestsApiController>(c => c.Get(1,2)))';
        alert(url);
    </script>
}
```

I get `/api/tests/1/2`, which is what I wanted.